# Building a Data.List.All from another Data.List.All

Tags: list, standard-library, agda

Suppose I have the following in scope:

```
A : Set
xs = [x1, x2, ..., xn] : List A
f : A → Set
```

I can then use [`Data.List.All`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.List.All.html) to make a type that contains `y1 : f x1`, `y2 : f x2`, ..., `yn : f xn` :

```
ys = [y1, y2, ..., yn] : All f xs
```

My quesiton is, suppose I have another function

```
g : {x : A} → f x → Set
```

Is there something in the standard library for turning that into a type `AllAll g ys` such that I can then have `z1 : g {x1} y1`, `z2 : g {x2} y2`, ..., `zn : g {xn} yn` in some `zs = [z1, ..., zn] : AllAll g ys`?

To clarify, here's how I'd implement it myself; my question is whether I have to do it this way or if something in the standard library (maybe `Data.List.All` itself?) that I could use:

```
data AllAll {A : Set} {f : A → Set} (g : {x : A} → f x → Set) : {xs : List A} → (ys : All f xs) → Set where
  [] : AllAll g []
  _∷_ : ∀ {x y xs ys} → g y → AllAll g ys → AllAll g {x ∷ xs} (y ∷ ys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the existing `All` for this. First define a function which 'forgets' the structure of `All`:

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.List.All
open import Data.Product

lower-All : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a} {P : A → Set p} {xs} → All P xs → List (∃ P)
lower-All [] = []
lower-All (x ∷ xs) = (_ , x) ∷ lower-All xs
```

Then simply compose this function with `All` itself:

```
AllAll : ∀ {a x p} {X : Set x} {A : X → Set a} (P : ∀ {x} → A x → Set p) 
        → ∀ {xs} → All A xs → Set _
AllAll P = λ xs → All (P ∘ proj₂) (lower-All xs)
```

One downside to this is that to pattern match on `ys : AllAll P xs` you must pattern match on `xs` first. Depending on how many functions you need to write which pattern match on `AllAll` this encoding may not be very convenient. One upside is you get additional 'nestings' for free:

```
AllAllAll : ∀ {l₀ l₁ l₂ l₃} 
   {A₀ : Set l₀}
   {A₁ : A₀ → Set l₁} 
   {A₂ : ∀ {x} → A₁ x → Set l₂}
   (A₃ : ∀ {x} {y : A₁ x} → A₂ y → Set l₃)
   → ∀ {xs₀} {xs₁ : All A₁ xs₀} (xs₂ : AllAll A₂ xs₁) → Set _
AllAllAll P = AllAll P
```

(Although if you find yourself in need of such a monster, perhaps consider refactoring your program....)

I leave as an exercise to prove the isomorphism between this version and the one in the OP.